# multiple python functions in one line causing problems

Tags: python

Why would these two lines of code do anything differently from each other?

```
visited_with_path.append(deep_copy(get_path_to_point(from_point)).append(point))
```

and

```
    x = deep_copy(get_path_to_point(from_point))
    x.append(point)
    visited_with_path.append(x)
```

I just spent a whole lot of time debugging until I tried making the above change (from first to second), and although it fixed the problem, I have no idea why. They seem like they should have identical functionality.

If it helps, visited_with_path is a list of lists of points, deep_copy makes a deep copy of this list of lists, get_path_to_point inputs a point and returns a list of points, and from_point and point are just points.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Because `.append` is in-place, so returns `None`

Comment: Even if `append` returned a reference to the list being appended to, that one-liner is far too unreadable to be recommended. Plus, different people might assume different things: I would assume `append` would return a reference to the list so that you could append multiple items at a time; you assume it returns a reference to the time *being* appended.

Answer (score 3):

`.append` doesn't return anything - it modifies the list in place, so you're basically appending `deep_copy(get_path_to_point(from_point))` to `visited_with_path`, which returns `None`, and then trying to `.append(point)` to `None`, which doesn't work.

Comment: The fact that functions with no explicit return return `None` rather than raising some sort of continuity error has tripped up many a person when debugging.